# Stop telegram bot command

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegraf

I am writing the telegram bot using node.js and telegraf. I ran into the question how to make the /stop command so, that user won't be able enter messages until he presses the restart button at the bottom. I tried to use bot.stop() and bot.leaveChat(), but that doesn't work; My code now:

```
const stop = async ctx => {
    ctx.reply('Your account was deleted and all subscriptions was cancelled')

    await CurrencyController.deleteUserCurrencies(ctx) //deletes user's subscriptions from database
    await UserController.deleteUser(ctx) //deletes user from database
    bot.stop() //doesn't work correctly
};


bot.command('stop', async ctx => await stop(ctx))
```

Now result of code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB3Xk.png), as you can see bot wasn't stopped for user, it just stopes in node.js, so I need to restart it with terminal.

I need [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lmmK.png)  result of function, it can be done with hands when you press stop and block bot in it's profile